# Can't find assets folder

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replicate a site, so I downloaded all the folders of it and changed it. It worked, but I have a problem with the following part,it doesn't show anything after "Featured Highlights" , but it should show some scrolling pictures. I don't have my assets folder, or better, I don't have this path assets/img, all the pictures are saved in my images folder. I have the js files too.

```
 <section data-scroll-index="3" class="section work-section border-top-g">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center section-heading">
                <div class="col-lg-15 text-center">
                    <h6><span class="text-theme">Highlights</span></h6>
                    <h3>Featured Highlights</h3>
                    <p>Here are some awards, articles, documents, certificates, and whatever else I am proud of.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="owl-carousel lightbox-gallery" data-items="3" data-nav-dots="true" data-md-items="3" data-sm-items="2" data-xs-items="2" data-xx-items="1" data-space="30" data-autoplay="true">
                <div class="work-box mb-4">
                    <div class="work-img">
                        <a class="gallery-link" href="assets/img/Graduation.jpg">
                            <img src="images/Graduation.jpg" title="Graduation" alt="Magna Cum Laude Graduation">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="work-info">
                        <div class="meta">
                            <span class="text-theme">2nd Bachelor's Graduation!</span>
                        </div>
                        <h5>Graduation Photo, December 2022</h5>
                        <p>I did it! I got my second bachelor's degree in computer science, somehow with Magna Cum Laude latin distiction too!</p>
                        <div class="btn-bar">
                            <a class="link-effect gallery-link" href="assets/img/Graduation.jpg">View Picture <i class="bi bi-arrow-up-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="work-box mb-4">
                    <div class="work-img">
                        <a class="gallery-link" href="assets/img/2023_Cybercamp_Anon_2.JPG">
                            <img src="images/2023_Cybercamp_Anon_2.JPG" title="Cyber Camp 2023" alt="CSU Cyber Camp 2023">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="work-info">
                        <div class="meta">
                            <span class="text-theme">CyberChallenge 2022</span>
                        </div>
                        <h5>CyberChallenge 2022</h5>
                        <p> I had the opportunity to attend this amazing project. CyberChallenge taught me about penetration testing, Osint, Cryptography and not only in a theorical way, but I had the opportunityto try all this and earn experience in this field. It was based on Capture The flag game, whiche made me cooperate with other guys verusus other teams.
                        

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                
                <div class="work-box mb-4">
                    <div class="work-img">
                        <a class="gallery-link" href="assets/img/Cybersec_Intern_Poster.jpg">
                            <img src="images/Cybersec_Intern_Poster.jpg" title="Cybersecurity internship Poster" alt="Cybersecurity internship Poster">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="work-info">
                        <div class="meta">
                            <span class="text-theme">CyberSecurity Internship Team</span>
                        </div>
                        <h5>Poster showing the cybersecurity internship team at Colorado State University</h5>
                        <p>Thanks to the great team at Colorado State University I have been able to further my skills in ways school alone would not have taught.</p>
                        <div class="btn-bar">
                            <a class="link-effect gallery-link" href="assets/img/Cybersec_Intern_Poster.jpg">View Picture <i class="bi bi-arrow-up-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="work-box mb-4">
                    <div class="work-img">
                        <a class="gallery-link" href="assets/img/Biocybersecurity_Winners.jpg">
                            <img src="images/Biocybersecurity_Winners.jpg" title="Third Place Winners!" alt="Cybersecurity competition winners">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="work-info">
                        <div class="meta">
                            <span class="text-theme">BioCybersecurity Hackathon 3rd Place Winners</span>
                        </div>
                        <h5>Placed 3rd at the Bio-Cybersecurity Hackathon</h5>
                        <p>Blake Davis, Tyson O'Leary and I placed third at the annual Biocybersecurity competition. It was an fun and challenging event that involved problems that bordered the intersection of biochemistry and computer science. Check out this article about the challenge -&gt;&gt; <a href="https://natsci.source.colostate.edu/top-3-sweep-computer-science-students-propel-winning-teams-at-bio-cybersecurity-student-challenge/">Article</a></p>
                        <div class="btn-bar">
                            <a class="link-effect gallery-link" href="assets/img/Biocybersecurity_Winners.jpg">View Picture <i class="bi bi-arrow-up-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I guess I'm missing this script

```
    <script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you try replacing `"assets/img/` into `images` ?

Comment: @underscore yep, but it doesn't show me any image anyway

Comment: how are you opening the html? through file system? or local server?

Comment: also please add your folder structure to the question.